# Tomcat services is not starting after enabling SSL - https

Tags: apache, ssl, tomcat, https

Tomcat services is not starting after enabling SSL.

My application is hosted in one of the server in apache tomcat but in http 8080 port. I want to enable https for my application.

I generated key using the following commannd

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\Users\app.keystore
```

and I changed my server.xml connector 
from

```
<Connector acceptCount="100"
connectionTimeout="20000"
executor="tomcatThreadPool"
maxKeepAliveRequests="15"
port="${bio.http.port}"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
redirectPort="${bio.https.port}"/>
```

to

```
<Connector
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
port="8443" maxThreads="200"
scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="C:\Users\app.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

But the services are not starting after changing it.

Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What doe the log files like `catalina.log` and others say? Anny Exceptions with stack traces?

Answer (score 0):

Usually key store files are located in the conf folder of tomcat (you can keep it anywhere). Can you add the key store inside the conf folder and change `keystoreFile="conf/app.keystore"`in the server.xml

Comment: Are you able to start tomcat without SSL? Also add the option `-Djavax.net.debug=all`  when starting tomcat with ssl, ,it will give a hint about the failure.

Comment: I am able to start tomcat without SSL. Let me try to add this in startup file